# How can I pass DropdownList Selected value with JavaScript to Controller in Asp.net MVC 4?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function Gonder() {
    var Liste = document.getElementById("BenimListe");
}
</script>

<form action="Para/Index" method="post">

Bir Ay Seçiniz
    <select id="BenimListe" onchange="Gonder()">
        <option></option>
        <option id="1">Ocak</option>
        <option id="2">Şubat</option>
        <option id="3">Mart</option>
        <option id="4">Nisan</option>
        <option id="5">Mayıs</option>
        <option id="6">Haziran</option>
        <option id="7">Temmuz</option>
        <option id="8">Ağustos</option>
        <option id="9">Eylül</option>
        <option id="10">Ekim</option>
        <option id="11">Kasım</option>
        <option id="12">Aralık</option>
    </select>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Giriş Yap" />
</p>
```

I have months id (between 1-12) in options.

If I choose id=10 Ekim in Drowpdownlist, I want to send this id=10 to Para/Index Controller/Action Method.

I tried to do this with Javascript. But it did not work.

How can I do it with javascript or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVC then you should use the built-in HTML helper functions for MVC, so you would define your options in a `SelectList` and then bind that select list to a control:

```
@{
  IDictionary<int, string> months = new Dictionary<int, string> {
    {1, "Ocak"},
    {2, "Subat"},
    // etc.
  }

  SelectList monthsSelect = new SelectList(months, "Value", "Key");
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  Html.DropDownList("BenimListe", monthsSelect);
  <button type="submit" value="Giriş Yap" />
}
```

MVC will take care of the rest.  Your selection(s) will be posted back to the controller action method.

Comment: I can not see neither months nor dropdownlist.I only see small button.If i click the small button it gives error.Also What to write Controller parameter ( list , string , int ) ?